# div keeps falling out of parent

Tags: css, html

Ok so i am using the css below but #profile_side keeps falling out of #wrap_p? What am I doing wrong? I tried googling it...

```
         #wrap_p{


            border-style: solid;
        }
        #profile_side{
            width: 20%;
            float: right;
            padding: 10px;
            border-style:dashed;
            border-color: gray;
        }
        #profile_main{
            width: 70%;

            padding:10px;
            border-style:dashed;
            border-color: gray;
        }
```

here's the html:

```
    <div id="wrap_p">
    <div id="profile_side">
    <img src="/img.png" width="100%"/>
            <big>username</big>
            <p>user information</p>
    </div>
    <div id="profile_main">
            main user stuff
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unless you show us the HTML to which this CSS applies, we can't see how these CSS classes relate to each other.  Also, describe your problem better. "Falling out" isn't very clear/meaningful, especially if you don't tell us what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @sepster done, please take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:** Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#wrap_p`

Check this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WsHAT/1/

`overflow: hidden` is used to tell the browser to hide any content that overflows the size of the element. But for this to work, the element must have a specified height value.

For elements with no height specified or `height: auto` (as in your case), this basically expands out the element to show all contents.

Comment: Yes. That should do it. Do check the jsfiddle demo too.

Comment: Just a second, i'll add some explanation to the answer regarding how this works.

Comment: i want to understand the method behind this

Comment: I've put in how `overflow: hidden` works for elements with no height specified. Note that when you don't specify any height, it is implicitly `height: auto`